# Adding optional parameter to stored procedure ,and if i didnt pass that param then all details has to fetch

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to add an optional param in stored procedure and if i call that stored procedure with optional param ,respected output should be fetched and if didnt pass param value in call then it should fetch all values..

i have already tried and student_marks should be optional, if i pass 90 as marks in param then ,the student with 90 marks in all subjects should be fetched .. if i pass only student name then the student with all subjects with marks to be fetched..

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS students_details $$
CREATE PROCEDURE students_details(IN name INT(11), IN marks CHAR(20))
  BEGIN 
    SELECT 
      student_name,
      student_id,
      subject_name,
      student_marks
    FROM students 
    where student_name = name (declared in param)
    and student_marks =  marks (optional param); 

  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

required output :  if i run  call students_details('john',80) ,  then the john's details has to be fetched ..(john with 80 marks in subjects)  ....

if i run call students_details('john')  only john as first param then the output should be john's all subjects with marks ..

Comment: Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: i am new to stored procedure concept .. if i didnt pass the second param then all details should be fetched..how can i handle this ..??

Comment: You need to pass both params in your call statement  otherwise ERROR 1318 (42000): Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE sandbox.p; expected 2, got 1 so you could pass something you could test .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input should include all the param (mandatory). So for optional you can use ('') like  `call students_details('john','')`

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS students_details $$
CREATE PROCEDURE students_details(IN name INT(11), IN marks CHAR(20))
  BEGIN 

IF(marks='') THEN
    SELECT 
      student_name,
      student_id,
      subject_name,
      student_marks
    FROM students 
    WHERE student_name = name;
ELSE
SELECT 
      student_name,
      student_id,
      subject_name,
      student_marks
    FROM students 
    WHERE student_name = name 
    AND student_marks =  marks; 
END IF;
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```